# How can I match the same column value in different tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables, Table A is the parent, Table B is the child. Both tables have the column "order_number".

I want to find the value in the "order_number" column in Table A, that matches the value of the "order_number" column in Table B, then I'll save the "id" of the Table A record in another column of the Table B record.

I'm having trouble coming up with an activerecord query to find the matching column value. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activerecord query to find the matching column value:

I think this should do it:

```
TableA.where(order_number: TableB.pluck(:order_number))
```

Then you can loop over it to update the tableB column for TableA id like below(assuming its called table_a_id)

```
tablea_records = TableA.where(order_number: TableB.pluck(:order_number))
tablea_records.each do |a|
  b.where(order_number:a.order_number).update_all(table_a_id: a.id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Would this also work if the two tables aren't related, or does it only work when one table inherits from the other?

Comment: `TableA.where(order_number: TableB.pluck(:order_number))` In this query we are basically finding values in tableA that have a certain  order_number.   We could change it to: `TableA.where(order_number: RandomTable.pluck(:random_column))` and it will still work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad the answer helped. Thank you :)