# Connect Email fields in Two Models (Find_each yielding stack too deep error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models (`Author` and `User`) that both have `email` fields.  A `User` `has_many` `Authors`, and an `Author` should belong to a `User`.

I need to find a way to look through the data and set `author.user_id` to the corresponding `user.id` when there is a match.

It theoretically works with a `connect_to_user` method I put in the `author.rb` model:

```
  def connect_to_user
    User.find_each do |user|
      if self.email == user.email
        self.update(user_id: user.id)
      end

      if user.chosen_author_id == nil
        user.update(chosen_author_id: self.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

However, when I try do do this in the console with `Author.all.find_each(&:connect_to_user)` it gives me a "stack level too deep" error and crashes everything.

I looked at posts involving [pluck](https://ackoverflow.com/questions/4473229/rails-server-says-port-already-used-how-to-kill-that-process) like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248029/how-can-i-match-the-same-column-value-in-different-tables), but I can't find anything that works.

I also tried a controller method like this:

```
User.all.find_each do |user|
  authors = Author.where(email: user.email)
  authors.each do |author|
    author.update(user_id: user.id)
  end
end
```

But it's still "stack level too deep".

Can anyone help me refactor in a way that doesn't make my computer start wheezing and smoking?

Comment: Do you have any active record hooks on either of the models?

Comment: `stack level too deep` generally happens when you accidentally call methods recursively, you need to provide more or full code of `User` and `Author` models to  find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a method like this to the `User` model that will connect all matching `authors` to the current `User` instance based on the user's email address.

```
# in app/model/user.rb
def find_and_connect_authors_with_same_email
  authors = Author.where(email: email)
  authors.update_all(user_id: id)
end
```

And would call it like this to connect all existing users with authors:

```
User.find_each(&:find_and_connect_authors_with_same_email)
```

Keep in mind that this only connects users and authors based on their email address once. But not again when an email changes or new records are created. It might be better to run callbacks on both  `Author` and `User` records before `save`. Or to not match by email add all and only store the email on the `User` model and making sure that there are no `Author` without an associated `User`. But what makes or sense or is practical depends on your application and your specific use-case.